# Обрезка некоторой области на картинке Python

Tags: python, opencv, crop

Есть картинка  с желтым залитым кругом на черном фоне

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким способом можно обрезать эту картинку до краев круга, чтобы получилось такое(картинка немного растянулась):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нужно, картину  с кругом на черном фоне получаю из такой[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот  таким кодом:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

hsv_min = np.array((0, 77, 17), np.uint8)
hsv_max = np.array((208, 255, 255), np.uint8)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fn = 'buttons/bar.png'
    img = cv.imread(fn)
    hsv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    thresh = cv.inRange(hsv, hsv_min, hsv_max)
    contours0, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    file_num = 0
    for cnt in contours0:
    if len(cnt) > 4:
        # create a new image with same dimensions as original image
        ellipse_img = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3), dtype = "uint8")
        print(cnt)
        ellipse = cv.fitEllipse(cnt)
        cv.ellipse(ellipse_img, ellipse, (255, 255, 255), 2)

        # save new image
        filename = 'ellipse' + str(file_num) + '.jpg'
        cv.imwrite(filename, ellipse_img)

        # increment counter in filename
        file_num += 1
```

Comment: на ютубе это видео удалили, но есть в вк. половину можно промотать и там будет обработка изображения https://m.vk.com/video-16108331_456254375?list=8539a496ac25e65fe9&from=wall-3183750_295406

Comment: эх, понимать бы  это

Comment: там вроде подробно объяснено.для начала запомни и повтори а понимание патом придёт.

Comment: а ну по видосу все понятно, понять бы ка получить эти координаты у меня

Comment: ну вбивай любые, выводи итог,корректируй координаты и так пока не получится правильно. повторить раз 5 всего

Comment: так проблема  в чем, входная картинка всегда разная

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Диапазон для inRange выбран изначально неверно и можно сделать сильно проще:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

hsv_min = np.array((18, 200, 200), np.uint8)
hsv_max = np.array((23, 255, 255), np.uint8)

fn = '6dd0L.png' # полная картинка
img = cv.imread(fn)
hsv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
thresh = cv.inRange(hsv, hsv_min, hsv_max)
output = cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh, 8, cv.CV_32S)
stats = output[2]
i=np.argmax(stats[1:,4])+1
crop=img[stats[i,1]:stats[i,1]+stats[i,3], stats[i,0]:stats[i,0]+stats[i,2],:]
cv.imshow('test', crop)
```

Вырезается наибольший по площади оранжевый объект на картинке и все.

Comment: Такс спасибо. Градиентность  на оранжевом круге учитывается?

Comment: В определенной мере учитывается, 18-23 диапазон цветового тона, надо больше - меняйте. Сделайте imshow(thresh) и увидите что  входит в inRange, а что нет.

Comment: Супер, спасибо, работает.

Answer (score 1):

Обычная задача на нахождение объекта перед тем, как его сможет обработать нейронная сеть. Как я понял, у вас довольно статическое изображение: то есть отсутствует деформация формы в виде небольшого растяжения объекта и подобные штучки, подрывающие все основно. Для таких случаев я бы порекомендовал CNN сети, однако это довольно дорого для вашей задачи. Вы уже смотрели в сторону cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, method)? По мне так идеальное решение. Для начала в редакторе графики кропнем сам кружок, после обработаем изображение в терминале как то так:

```
import cv2

file=r"template.png"

gray=cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

(_ret, thresh)=cv2.threshold(gray, 170, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

cv2.imwrite(file, thresh)
```

То есть сохраним его как одноканальный threshold и больше не мучаемся с этим. Это мы получили шаблон объекта, который ищем. Что то такое:
[image: template.png]

Приведу небольшой пример того, как можно найти координаты объекта:

```
import cv2

class files:

    image       =r"image.png"
    template    =r"template.png"

""" Для нашей задачи достаточно сразу читать все в GRAYSCALE и не морочиться с переводом в него.
    Вот тут осторожней: один канал у template и три у image.
    Нужно threshold или Candy( или как его там.. ) применить на image.
"""
image       =cv2.imread(files.image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
template    =cv2.imread(files.template, cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)

(_ret, threshold)=cv2.threshold(image, 170, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

""" Можно поиграть с методами (3 аргумент),
    наиболее подходящими вам.
"""
match=cv2.matchTemplate(threshold, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

""" Теперь нам совсем просто получить начальные координаты найденного совпадения с шаблоном.
    Я реализую это принимая за внимание наличие только одоного круга.
    Однако, если ваша задача предполагает наличие нескольких кругов на изображении,
    то можно воспользоваться этим:

    location=numpy.where(match >= 0.9)

    for y, x in zip(*location):
        код

    Поиграйте со значением 0.9 и все должно получиться.
    //
    max_loc, (x, y) - левые верхние координаты.
    Прибавим к этому размер template и получим правые нижние.
"""
(_min_val, _max_val, _min_loc, max_loc)=cv2.minMaxLoc(match)

left_upper  =max_loc
right_lower =\
(   left_upper[0] + template.shape[0],
    left_upper[1] + template.shape[1]
)

""" Для наглядности вырежим этот фрагмент и покажем в окне:
"""
this_object=image[ left_upper[1]:right_lower[1], left_upper[0]:right_lower[0] ]

cv2.imshow("this_object", this_object)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Текс, спасибо. Скопировал код, подтсавил изображения, но получил ошибку https://prnt.sc/srqdol

Comment: Это действительно странно, ведь у меня все работает. Я хочу сказать, что ошибки cv2 это отдельный шедевр информативности, и я не могу в них достаточно разобраться без самого кода. Вот пакет того, что я использовал: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4Aji/4jEttafdw

Comment: Ну лично я ровано скопировал твой код. А и есть еще одна загводка, на входной картинке неизвестно какая буква будет.

Comment: Можно закрасить букву белым. То есть я думаю, что выгодней будет игнорировать наличие буквы, чем делать несколько шаблонов для разных букв или делать черную дырку под все буквы, что немного больше понизит точность.

Comment: Ваш комментарий натолкнул меня на мысль о том, что у вас банально нет тех же изображений в тех же путях. Я убрал используемые в коде изображения и получил точно такую же ошибку. Попробуйте вывести их через print. Если будет None, то вот и нашлась ошибка.

Comment: Пути я поменял, картинки подставил свои

Comment: https://del.dog/emoppaghiw.txt вот такой код получился

Comment: и как сделать игнорирование буквы?

Comment: Окей. Я уверен, что проблема в путях. Вы уже пробовали вывести значение картинок? None означает то, что они не смогни загрузиться, но ошибки cv2 из вежливости не поднял.

Comment: Такс, заработало, не знаю как решил. Ну код отработал так сказать, не ровно - https://prnt.sc/srqsjf

Comment: Что ваш, что мой, никаких проблем не возникает. Перепроверьте ваши изображения. https://prnt.sc/srqu9a

Comment: Подашаманил картинки, а теперь вопрос, как получить координаты найденой картинки?

Comment: Можете почитать мои комментарии в коде. Там это описано.